# I need help getting links for every page that doesn't include ?page=number after the link

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the links from all the pages on https://apexranked.com/. I tried using

```
url = 'https://apexranked.com/'

page = 1 

while page != 121: 
    url = f'https://apexranked.com/?page={page}'
    print(url) 
    page = page + 1
```

however, if you click on the page numbers it doesn't include a https://apexranked.com/?page=number as you see from https://www.mlb.com/stats/?page=2. How would I go about accessing and getting the links from all pages if the page doesn't include ?page=number after the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page is not reloading when you click on page 2. Instead, it is firing a *GET* request to the website's backend.
The request is being sent to : https://apexranked.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
In addition, several parameters are parsed directly onto the previous url.
`?action=get_player_data&page=3&total_pages=195&_=1657230896643`

**Parameters** :

- action: As the endpoint can handle several purpose, you must indicate the performed action. Surely a mandatory parameter, don't omit it.
- page: indicates the requested page (i.e the index you're iteraring over).
- total_pages: indicates the total number of page (maybe it can be omitted, otherwise you can scrap it on the main page)
- _: this one corresponds to an unix timestamp, same idea as above, try to omit and see what happens. Otherwise you can get a unix timestamp quite easily with `time.time()`

Once you get a response, it yields a rendered HTML, maybe try to set `Accept: application/json` field in request headers to get a Json, but that's just a detail.

All these informations wrapped up:

```py
import requests
import time

url = "https://apexranked.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"

# Issued from a previous scraping on the main page
total_pages = 195

params = {
    "total_pages": total_pages,
    "_": round(time.time() * 1000),
    "action": "get_player_data"
}

# Make sure to include all mandatory fields
headers = {
    ...
}

for k in range(1, total_pages + 1):
     params['page'] = k
     res = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
     # Make your thing :)
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't exactly know what you mean but if you for example wanna get the raw text u can do it with requests

```
import requests
# A loop that will keep going until the page is not found.
while(requests.get(f"https://apexranked.com/?page={page}").status_code != 404):
    #scrap content e.g whole page 
    link = f"https://apexranked.com/?page={page}"
    page = page + 1
```

you can also add the link then to an array with `nameOfArray.append(link)`

Comment: I apologize if I worded it in a way that you didn't understand. Basically, I am trying to get the link to every page, however, right now I am only able to get the link from the first page but not the rest. The code that I provided works if the link was in the format https://apexranked.com/?page=2, if I wanted to go to page 2, however, if I try and go to page 2 it stays as https://apexranked.com/. Therefore, I am having trouble accessing all the pages, besides the first one and needed help with this.

Comment: Change line 5 to `link = f"https://apexranked.com/?page={page}"` and then you’ll have the link. Now you can use that to make an array

Comment: While looping until a 404 is reached does not seem like a great idea. You should also save the response of the while loop to a variable. This way you reduce the amount of requests you make by half.